# How to write data to running process repeatedly without getting deadlocked from reading another process output

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, deadlock, popen

I am using Python `Popen` to start two processes. I am reading from first by `stdout.read()`. And writing to another by `stdin.write()`. This leads to deadlock. So I added `stdin.close()` to the end  of writing method, but I cannot write to the closed pipe anymore. Is there a way to reopen the pipe? Or is there better solution? I cant use `communicate()`, because it waits for process to terminate and i need that process to keep running.

Simple method here:

```
def send(input):
#here i need to reopen the pipe 
proc.stdin.write(input)
proc.stdin.close()
```

Comment: Do you just pass process1's output data to process2's input or do you somehow modify the data?

Comment: I am not passing process1's output data to process2's input directly. First process output (which I am reading) depends on input of the second process but not directly. This dependence comes from Network communication of these processes.

Comment: Are you on Unix/Linux? I would consider `select()` but it is not fully available on Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately I am on Windows. I am thinking about using multithreading, I hope that might solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe you could use some kind of non-blocking calls. I don't know exactly. Your question is very specific without provided context. It might be a case of a so-called XY problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Problem solved, for reading I am using non-blocking stream reader (with timeout). And for writing I had to add `\n` to the end of input. And call the `flush()` function after that.